# How can i change the focus to other textfield after i complete max characters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How do I change the focus to other node after completion max characters without pressing next/done in Flutter ?. How do I pass the control to other TextField using Focus node. I want to pass the control to next textfield after 4 characters of every textfield.

```
Widget serailKey1() {
        return TextField(
            controller: controller_key1,
            focusNode: _serialKeyFN1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
            style: textStyle,
            maxLength: 4,

            decoration: new InputDecoration(

              counterText: "",
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(0.0),
                ),
              ),
          ),
          onEditingComplete: ()=> FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_serialKeyFN2),

        );
      }

      Widget serailKey2() {
        return TextField(
            controller: controller_key2,
            focusNode: _serialKeyFN2,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            style: textStyle,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
            maxLength: 4,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
              counterText: "",
              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  const Radius.circular(0.0),
                ),
              ),

            ),
          onEditingComplete: ()=> FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_serialKeyFN3),

        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
    FocusNode fNode = FocusNode();
    ...
    TextField(onChanged: (value){ 
      if(value.length == 4) 
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(fNode);
    }),
    TextField(focusNode: fNode),
```